# What ever happened to the velo 2g gripper?

Tags: ros, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Back in 2013 Willow Garage designed and potentially distributed a fantastic gripper called the **velo 2g**. From the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P4GtdgdQK4)
it looks like it was perfect for gripping household objects.

I am looking for a gripper for the Baxter robot and I have yet to find anything as slim and versatile as the velo 2g appears. Does anyone know if this gripper (or just its design) is available? What happened to it?
[gripper http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/velo_white_3.JPG](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/velo_white_3.JPG)

Sorry in advance for this question being a little off topic. I didn't know where else to ask it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203451/what-ever-happened-to-the-velo-2g-gripper?/) by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not believe the Velo 2G gripper is available from any source right now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1